# PostgreSQL only NOTIFY after transaction complete

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I have an API that inserts a row into a TableA, and then inserts N rows into TableB, with a foreign key set from TableA.id.

In another script, I'm using `LISTEN` to listen to inserts, but I only want to be notified once the whole set of queries is completed. I was hoping that using transactions would help this, but `NOTIFY`, whilst waiting for all queries to succeed, will still insert on the order they were executed.

Does anyone have a solution? Is it possible to trigger events between two different node services?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Insert all data using a [pg-promise transaction](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise/wiki/Learn-by-Example#transactions), and then use [node-ipc](https://github.com/RIAEvangelist/node-ipc) to send notification to the other process when the transaction has finished.

It is a fairly standard solution, you don't need to invent anything. And use of `LISTEN` in this case is a bad idea, it will consume an extra connection, and [is known to be unreliable](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/issues/967).

Comment: Thanks. This probably is the best solution.